# Are two Google accounts needed to run AdSense on both YouTube and Blogger?

Tags: google-adsense, blogger, google-adsense-policies

I don't have websites of my own. But i have 1 Google AdSense linked to my YouTube Channel (1 Google account for all).

Can I create another Google account for Blogger and link it to a new AdSense account?

It does not allow me to link a single AdSense account with YouTube and Blogger both.

Or maybe a different family member living in same address can have a separate Google AdSense account as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to have multiple AdSense accounts.    Just use your first account to generate ad-units, and add these to your blog as HTML/Javascript gadgets.    (Assuming of course that your blog meets Google's content guidelines for AdSense.)

Comment: my adsense is youtube hosted and I also want to use it for blogspot account. but it's not showing any ads on blogspot after monitizing with the adsense account